# Any good reason my company's non-looping code does dict(enumerate(list)).get(number) instead of just list[number]?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

There's a legacy piece of Python code at my company that I'm considering refactoring.

Instead of just accessing `sys.argv[0]` and `sys.argv[3]` and such, it first does `args_dict = dict(enumerate(sys.argv))` and then accesses system parameters as `args_dict.get(0)` and `args_dict.get(3)`.

This seems silly to me.

I'm wondering if it's a typo left over from some sort of refactor away from a more complicated thing that I can now also refactor away.

I noticed that some of the more complex codebases using this pattern do pass `args_dict` to methods as a parameter named `args_dict` ... but it seems like `sys.argv` could just as easily be passed as `args_list` or even just called directly from those methods?

Is there any possible reason, such as safety when using an out-of-bounds argument place number, that it's actually preferable to access things with a dict as `.get(number)` rather than with a list as `[number]`?  Or can I safely refactor for simplicity?

Comment: `args_dict.get(i)` returns `None` when the key `i` does not exist. `sys.argv[i]` will raise an `IndexError` in this case.

Comment: I think that might actually be preferable!  Maybe the answer is as simple as "whoever coded this first thought that quietly swallowing problems was the best graceful degradation."  I'll have to think about each script's context business-wise and decide if I think they're right about that.

Comment: I don't think it's a safety issue. It's just shorter than `arg_3 = sys.argv[3] if len(sys.argv[3]) > 3 else None`. If that CLI argument is optional, your code needs logic to handle both its presence and absence.

Comment: If you refactor do it properly and use `argparse` :)

Comment: Use tombstoning. Generate a random string and whenever either variant provides a different result, you log that. Commit the code with a timestamp when it was marked as dead (hence the name of this technique). You can then leave it running for some extended period of time and eventuall go through the logs. If you don't find the random string there, you know it's really dead code and can remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the code were just using indexing, there'd be no safety difference: attempting to access a nonexistent index in a list will throw an `IndexError`; attempting to access a nonexistent key in a dict will throw a `KeyError`. Either way you have to either catch the exception or make sure you're within bounds somehow.

But the code isn't using `args_dict[i]`, it's using `args_dict.get(i)`, which doesn't throw an error; it just returns `None` if the key is missing. So maybe that's the whole point? Lists don't have an analogous method.

I can understand copying from `sys.argv` into another variable, especially if that other var might potentially be initialized via a different mechanism than the command-line arguments. Conversion to a dict would also make sense if the keys were configuration parameter names or something. But I agree – just using the indexes as keys seems odd, and I'm not sure avoiding `IndexError`s is a good enough reason to do something that confusing to readers of your code.

In general, if you're going to process CLI arguments, it's better to process them into something more meaningful than a 1-to-1 mapping from the way they arrived in `sys.argv`. The built-in `argparse` is pretty powerful; there are also add-on modules (I like [`argh`](https://pypi.org/project/argh/)) which can do such useful things as automatically turning CLI arguments into method parameters.